# Как ограничить доступ к ПУ proxmox?

Tags: access, веб-сервер, безопасность, access-control, proxmox

Есть debian с proxmox. У proxmox свой web сервер.
Как увеличить безопасность и ограничить доступ к web panel proxmox(с защитой от брутфорса и прочего ) ?
Сейчас ограничил с помощью iptables , разрешил только свой ip. 
Хотелось бы иметь доступ еще с мобильного телефона или еще из других сетей ( которые заранее не известны ).

Может возможно узнать подсеть мегафоновских ip-адресов и разрешить их в iptables? Так же разрешить только российские ip ?

Например в nginx можно ограничить количество запросов в секунду + поставить доп. авторизацию по логину\паролю.

Comment: Вариант 1) Подними VPN - и разреши доступ только из локальной сети и сети VPN 2) настрой file2ban https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Fail2ban

Answer (score 1):

Сделать что-то нестандартное.
Например повесить скрипт авторизации, который при правильном пароле будет устанавливать определенную куку, а nginx по этой куке уже будет пускать или не пускать собственно к панели (дальше авторизация панели и т.п.).Скрипт можно сделать по необычном адресу, вроде http://www.domain.com:7361/mytest-jguhdvfdnaj.php

Comment: Мысль конечно хорошая, но если бы четко знал как это сделать, я бы не задавал тут подобного вопроса.
У Proxmox на сколько я знаю свой web сервер.